# Geometry subdivisions in threejs

Tags: 3d, three.js, mesh

I'm trying to subdivide a plane in threejs.  I'm currently using on my mesh THREE.SubdivisionModifier( subdiv ) which applies the Catmull-Clark algorithm, but i only want simple subdivisions (I don't want the position of the existing vertices to change).

Sorry if it's an obvious question, but I really couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [TessellateModifier](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/modifiers/TessellateModifier.js) is what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this is gonna be useful. However for the moment I found out i can cut my mesh simply by adding the number of cuts after setting the size: for example new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 7, 7,3,3 )  creates a plane with three cuts.. thats what i needed :)